# Removing .txt from my file name and sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

Pleas help guys!! In the section of code below (which works great btw), I keep getting .txt in the actually file name and sheet name. I have been looking at what I need to take out to solve this but I can't work it out. I am pretty new to VBA so I am doing my best Please help?!

```
 'Opens the folder to location to select txt file
  fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If fileToOpen <> False Then
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    End If
 'Creates the file name based on txt file name
  fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1)
 'Creates the sheet name based on the active txt file
  sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

 'Rename the original text file
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" & "DNU_" & fileName & ".txt")
```

Comment: What is your problem/error ? Getting a run-time error ? or wrong values for `fileName` or `sheetName` ?

Comment: When assigning `sheetName` shouldn't you reference `fileName` rather than the active workbook name? And in the SaveAs line, remove the `& ".txt"`.

Comment: There is no error but when the process is complete, I have the words .txt actually in the filename, it also appears in the sheet name. So for example, it appears as Test.txt.txt as the file format is .txt. I need it to just read Test with the .txt only as file format, not making up any of the name.

Comment: Since you are trying to open a Textfile, which has only 1 sheet in it, you can use `sheetName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` to get the sheet's name

Comment: @SJR Thank you for that, it worked perfectly.  The reason there is a sheet name is that the next line of code which I didn't include stupidly is 'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\BACS File Original\" & _
    fileName & ".CSV"), FileFormat:=xlCSV'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could just use your sheetname as the filename too, as you already remove the ".txt" from the sheetname.

```
'Opens the folder to location to select txt file
  fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If fileToOpen <> False Then
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    End If

 'Creates the sheet name based on the active txt file
  sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

 'Rename the original text file
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" & "DNU_" & sheetName & ".txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex and extract file name without extension and use it

```
public String extractFileName(String fullPathFile){
        try {
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(EXTRACT_FILE_NAME_REGEX);
            Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(fullPathFile);
            if (regexMatcher.find()){
                return regexMatcher.group(1);
            }
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
            LOG.info("extractFileName::pattern problem <"+fullPathFile+">",ex);
        }
        return fullPathFile;
    }
```

Comment: Yes but this is an Excel VBA question.

Comment: What on earth is a regex?

Comment: remplace EXTRACT_FILE_NAME_REGEX by "([^\\\\/:*?\"<>|\r\n]+$)"